# NSUserDefaults write string and clean it after

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, plist, nsuserdefaults

I write a string in NSUserDefaults

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: myString forKey: @ "String"];
```

Then I take out this string from NSUserDefaults and return

```
- (NSString *) retrieveString
{
     NSString * recoveredString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: @ "String"];
     return recoveredString;
}
```

Then in viewDidLoad write the returned string in another string

```
NSString * filePath = [self retrieveString];
```

I need to delete a string of NSUserDefaults after I was returning to her in - (NSString *) retrievestring

I do so

```
    - (NSString *) retrieveString
        {
             NSString * recoveredString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: @ "String"];
             [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey: @ "String"];
             return recoveredString;

        }
```

But this does not work, the line is not deleted.
How to fix it

Thanks to all.

Comment: `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];`

Comment: @Kjuly Yeah, that's what I just wrote :)

Answer (score 0):

`NSUserDefaults` updates its data periodically only, not each and every time a setter or getter is called. If you want an immediate update, call

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: @user1307640 Immediately after the call to `removeObjectForKey:`.

Comment: Still doesn't work. NSString *recoveredString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"String"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]removeObjectForKey:@"String"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    return recoveredString;

Comment: @user1307640 because there's no reference to the string. You have to write `NSString *recoveredString = [[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"String"] retain] autorelease];`.

Comment: i use Automatic Reference Counting

Comment: @user1307640 And if you turn ARC off?

Comment: @user1307640 I'll see, just try turning it off for a moment.

Comment: @H2CO3 are you seriously suggesting he/she turns ARC off to fix one line of code?

Comment: @AndySinclair No, I'm suggesting he turns it off to see if it helps, and if so, it'd be easier to come up with a solution which doesn't involve turning it off.

Comment: `synchronize` save the NSUserDefaults data from memory to the file system. The same thing is done by NSUserDefaults from time to time. synchronize is usually not necessary. Yoy may need it during development when you force quit the app with Xcode's stop button. Anyway, it should not make any difference in this case because [[NSUserDefaults ..] objectForKey:...]  reads it's data from memory first.

Comment: I realized the problem. `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey: @ "String"];` delete rows from NSUserDefaults but it does not happen immediately, but after a couple of seconds, so if you just write another row then it prints the old and the new Add in memory, and when I Next we'll record it displays the string is out of memory in NSUserDefaults, and re-record a new memory.
But how to make the change to occur INSTANT?

Comment: @MatthiasBauch Bauch What do you think is better to use CoreData?

Comment: @user1307640 Do what I suggestted. `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];` is **exactly for this purpose.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `synchronize` call AND move your return call (so it is the last line in the method). So, your code should like this:

```
- (NSString *) retrieveString
{
    NSString * recoveredString = [NSString stringWithString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: @ "String"]];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey: @ "String"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    return recoveredString;
}
```

Comment: This still doesn't work because of loosing the reference to the string.

Comment: I am use Automatic Reference Counting. if i try this NSString *recoveredString = [[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"String"] retain] autorelease]; xcode shows error

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I have amended the code by adding a stringWithString call to make a copy of the string